# Updating field type from 'date' to 'string' in elasticsearch

Tags: codeigniter, elasticsearch, postman

I am new to Elasticsearch. I have created an index with few sub-types.

```
{
"rkb_search_v3": {
    "mappings": {
        "event": {
            "properties": {
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
                "start_date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to update `start_date` type to string as i am not able to search through it, it gives error `[error] => SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[4VaJ1zHkSsOaYid7rz6Ciw][rkb_search_v3][0]: SearchParseException[[rkb_search_v3][0]: from[-1],size[100]`

i am trying to update it using postman by following method

`PUT localhost:9200/rkb_search_v3/_mapping/event`

```
{
    "properties": {
        "start_date": {
            "type":   "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but its not updating. please help.

P.S.:Event type has data indexed in it.

Comment: You're solving the problem incorrectly here. `start_date` is supposed to be of type `date`. Can you post the query which failed? You should try to fix the query here instead of the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a field from a string to a date when it already has data, you need to re-index all the data.  Using the ES plugin is a great way to accomplish this.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html

Comment: just in case, i was not also able to update when there was no data in it. Can u point me that